# curve drawing with Cocos2D for iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, bezier, curve

I'm making a simple game using Cocos2D. The user can touch and trace a path for small moving objects. The objects then follow the path. This is similar to the Flight Control game mechanic.

how i can move the object like that.please help me to get out of this problem.any sample code or tutorial will help me more thank you .

Answer (score 0):

In your touchesEnded/touchesMoved method try and do this :

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if (touch) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    id animation = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:convertedPoint];
    [playerShip runAction:animation];
   }
```